# TypeScript Parameter<IFolderService[T]> "A spread argument must either have a tuple type or be passed to a rest parameter."

Tags: typescript, typescript-generics

```
public async insertToDB<T extends keyof IFolderService>(
        prismaAction: IFolderService[T],
        ...params: Parameters<IFolderService[T]>
    ): Promise<any>{
        return await prismaAction(...params);
    }
```

I would expect that the function accepts any methods from `IFolderService`, then the rest `...params`, is the parameter from `IFolderService[T]`.

Even if I try to use `any`, it still gives an error. Do I have to write this another way?

Comment: Why not just something like this `async function insertToDB<T extends (...args: any[]) => any>(
    prismaAction: T,
    ...params: Parameters<T>
) {
    return prismaAction(...params);
}
`